# bootstrap buttons getting smaller when active

Tags: css

Hey guys I have problem And I'm sitting all day trying to figure it out...

Problem is that if I click on button (succes, danger, custom) it gets a bit smaller:

[image]

When button becomes :active it will do this... and this applies only to btn class...

What could be the problem?
I tried setting active link font-size, but it's just make everything worse...

Comment: You need to share some code, Helping others to find the exact issue.

Comment: your css might be messing around with button, on button plz do inspect element and check on active state this way you'll figured it out on your own

Comment: Thank you for your tip!, I found what was the problem, stupid me added a: active font-size:11 on another div as global declaration...

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just writing my own comments as an answer as this help him to figured out the solution

your css might be messing around with button, on button plz do inspect element and check on active state this way you'll figured it out on your own